# Using xml:space without namespace declaration

Tags: xml, namespaces

I have recently received a lot of XML documents which use the xml:space attribute heavily. Looking at how it is used, I would say that the editor didn't exactly know [what xml:space is used for](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/).

However, I most wonder why the XML editor does not complain about the missing namespace declaration for xml:space. In my opinion there should be a

```
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

somewhere in the document.

**Is it possible to use xml:space without namespace declaration?**

Answers which include a W3C reference will be preferred. I was looking at ["The "xml:" namespace"](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace), but it is not clear to me from that document that I could omit the namespace declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "xml" prefix is implicitly declared. See here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl

Quote:

> The prefix xml is by definition bound to the namespace name
>   http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace. It MAY, but need not, be
>   declared, and MUST NOT be bound to any other namespace name. Other
>   prefixes MUST NOT be bound to this namespace name, and it MUST NOT be
>   declared as the default namespace.